# How do you create a directory structure in Git?

Tags: git, branch, gitlab, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am trying to understand how to create a directory structure in Git that maps to my development process.

BTW, I am a newbie to Git, but not in source control.

I am using GitLab as my repository manager.

I have added my repository into GitLab and successfully cloned the repository.

The development process I want to create is as follows:

> master | done | QA | INT

Whenever someone clones the repository, they will automatically see this branch structure and will work off the `int` branch.

I have tried running the commands thinking it would create the structure, but it does not appear so (maybe I am wrong).

```
git checkout -b Done master
git checkout -b QA Done
git checkout -b INT QA

git branch
```

> ```
>   Done
> * INT
>   QA
>   master
> ```

Anyway, I am assuming I am missing something simple (hopefully).

Does anyone have any insight as to how I can setup this simple branch hierarchy?

Thanks

Comment: What response are you getting from the commands?

Answer (score 10):

You might have some misunderstanding about git branches.

After your commands are run, the commits and branches in git are like this:
[image]

`A<-B` means `A is a parent of B` or `based on A, we make some changes and commit them, so we get a new commit B`. The blue dashed arrow means `the branch points to a commit`.

Now if we checkout `master` and make another commit `E`, the graph is like this:
[image]

Then we checkout `Done` and make another commit `F`, the graph becomes:
[image]

If we merge `Done` to `master`, via `git checkout master;git merge Done`, it is like:
[image]

In Git, a branch ref is a variable that stores the value or ref that it points to. The value is not constant. Every commit records the sha1 of its parent commit(s). The root commit `A` has 0 parents. The merge commit `G` has 2 parents. The left commits have 1 parent. `git log -1 <commit> --pretty=%P` or `git log -1 <commit> --pretty=raw` can show the parent sha1.

Comment: Incidentally, I think it's worth adding that Git is very different from most version control systems. For instance, branches in Mercurial actually hold each commit, and every commit is on exactly one branch, vs Git where branches just point at commits and a commit can be on many branches simultaneously. Branches in other VCSes tend to be more like those in Mercurial (although every VCS has its own quirks).

Comment: @torek thanks a lot for your info. I know little about other VCS.

Comment: Nice picture!  How did you create them ?

Comment: @Jayan It's created via `graphviz`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is already there. You've made your branches. Now, its up to collaborators to do some work. Below is a way how to set up a default branch, if it's different from `master`

To change the default branch in Gitlab:

1. Click Settings in the left-hand bar
2. Change the Default Branch to the desired branch
3. Click Save Changes

Comment: Thanks for the info.